# Reset state value in functional component in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have created cart functionality and I have managed this using useState hook. though I can change quantity of items but if I close the Modal, it can't reset. (I want quantity 0 on closing a Modal).

let [addonData, setAddonData] = useState([]);

Here if i open modal again after closing I get previous values, but I want 0 instead of that. Please check attached image for your reference.

I have tried but I got this error: **too many re-renders. react limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.**

So, If anyone have idea then please let me know.

Thanks in advance :)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For doing that, you'll probably need to fire a `reset` function on modal dismiss, but what that means exactly?!

#### Parent Component

Imagine that we have this modal which receives a state from the parent component.

```js
const MyParentComponent = () => {
  const [opened, setOpened] = useState(false);
  const [state, setState] = useState([])

  const onOpen = () => {
    setOpened(true)
  }

  const onDismiss = () => {
    setOpened(false)
    setState([])
  }

  return ( 
    <>
      {myComponent()}
      <Modal isOpened={opened} state={state} setState={setState} onDismiss={onDismiss} />
    </>
  )
}
```

What is happening here is that we pass a state from the Parent to the Modal Component, but every time we close the modal we reset the state we were passing to it.

This solve your problem, but check this section of the [beta.reactjs docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#resetting-state-at-the-same-position)

Comment: Hello Bruno, I have tried this one, but still I am getting the same error. i.e.  Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

should I have to use useEffect or something else? do you have any idea?

Comment: This error happens just when you close your Modal?

Comment: Beyond that, could you please show me your Modal, might be something being done inside it.

Comment: Hello Bruno, Please find Modal from the link attached. 

https://codeshare.io/4eEX6d

Comment: here I'm using clearify() on click of icon "X" to clear the state.